# Zend Navigation: current page

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

There is a method `isActive()` in `Zend_Navigation`. But it returns true for all the elements in the current path
(parent `li` is active and all the children too, even when the current is parent `li`).

Is there any method like `isCurrent()`, to determine whether the current menu item is the current page?

I just like to add custom class attribute to *just one*, current element in the whole nested tree of ul's and li's.

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? `isActive()` should return true only for the current page, not parent or child pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use your own navigation view script, but that's fairly simple. Then try:

```
$this->navigation()->findActive($this->yourNavContainer);
```

That will return an object, var dump it and you will see the data you need. I think the variable is simply called 'page'. Do this before you build your menu, pre/post dispatch, then in your viewscript, do an if statement to check this var against the current looped item (i guess your loop it in a foreach).

Answer (score 7):

easier with:

```
$activeElement = $view->navigation()->findOneBy('active', 1);
```

if you're inside your view script you can use:

```
$activeElement = $this->navigation()->findOneBy('active', 1);
```

Comment: Works better for me than the accepted answer. Thanks!